# Error occurred (ECONNREFUSED) while trying to proxy request React/ Express (npm run start)

Tags: reactjs, proxy, bundle, econnrefused

Hello and hope you are well.

When running `npm run start`  on my project, it is not working because it seems to build the files only once and not watch for it. So it is not compiling the FE part and only running server side.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node build.js",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx,mjs --max-warnings=0 --color || true",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx,mjs --max-warnings=0 --color --fix || true"
},
```

**bundle-server.js**

```
const app = express();

app.use(require("./build.js"));

app.listen(8081, () => console.log("Ready to compile and serve bundle.js"));
```

**index.js**

```
    app.use(
        "/bundle.js",
        require("http-proxy-middleware")({
            target: "http://localhost:8081/"
        })
    );
} else {
    app.use("/bundle.js", (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/bundle.js`));
}

///////////-------///////////

if (require.main == module) {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log("Server Listening"));
}
```

there is as well a **db.js**

```
const db = spicedPg(
    process.env.DATABASE_URL ||
    "postgres:postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/contacts"

);
```

When running `npm start` or `npm run start`, the following error is shown:

```
Server Listening
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /bundle.js from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8081/ (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I am not sure if this could be from the

```
const db = spicedPg(
   process.env.DATABASE_URL ||
   "postgres:postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/contacts"
```

as I am not passing the correct ref to call the database ? In addition, this is a `production` set up and not a dev one, so this could be the source too.

Where should I look in the code base to tackle this `ECONNREFUSED` ?

Please find the repo [here](https://github.com/Edith2019/final-portfolio)

Thank you for taking the time